# Pandas Display Strings as "Literals" in DataFrame Outputs

Tags: pandas

#### EDIT:

I should specify that I want the rich html output to show the escaped characters. It is nice to have the series in the correct form, and [@Stu Sztukowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5342700/stu-sztukowski) provided a helpful way to do that.

```
df['type:string'].apply(lambda x: repr(x))
```

However, what I really want to see is something like this:

[image: Screenshot of desired tabular output in VSCode]

#### Problem

I am wondering if there is a way to force pandas to display strings with their escape characters explicitly shown when the datatype is `string`. Currently, when displaying a Series, if the datatype is `object` then the escaped whitespace characters are shown explicitly. However, when that same series is converted to `string`, then it shows them as generic whitespace (or prints them).

#### Reproducible example:

Here is some code you can use to reproduce the effect.

```
import pandas as pd

string_data = ['foo\nbar', 'foo\tbar', '\nfoo\n\tbarbar', 'bar\rbaz', None]

data = {"type:object":string_data, "type:string":string_data}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.astype({'type:string':'string'})
```

Here are the outputs I see when viewing both series on their own:

```
>>> df['type:object']
0           foo\nbar
1           foo\tbar
2    \nfoo\n\tbarbar
3           bar\rbaz
4               None
Name: type:object, dtype: object
```

```
>>> df['type:string']
0         foo
bar
1         foo   bar
2    
foo
    barbar
3         bar
baz
4            <NA>
Name: type:string, dtype: string
```

I find the utility of the modern pandas>1.0 `string` datatype and its usage of `pd.NA` to be very helpful, so I would prefer to use the `type:string` column from this example. However, this makes it hard to view the strings in an intelligent way with other data, because the true contents of the string are obscured from me.

The problem only gets worse when looking at the DataFrame in .ipynb file outputs such as this view from VSCode:

[image: Example data table as output from VSCode]

As you can see, all of the escaped whitespace characters are shown as the same generic whitespace.

#### Conclusion

Does anyone know of a way to force pandas to display the strings as it does in the `type:object` column while keeping the datatype as `string`?

I checked through [this pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/options.html) thinking that it might be something fixable via `pd.set_option()` but I didn't see anything there.

Comment: print(df.to_string())

Comment: I just tried that and it results in the same formatting as the two example series I showed. The `type:string` column still doesn't have its escape characters printed explicitly. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/MoN0M86)

Comment: Looks like this is a feature request for Pandas as of the end of last year. [Here is a link to the pandas github post](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/46744) where it is suggested that using __repr__ to print objects be the default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Apply `repr()` as a lambda function.

```
df['type:string'].apply(lambda x: repr(x))
```

```
0           'foo\nbar'
1           'foo\tbar'
2    '\nfoo\n\tbarbar'
3           'bar\rbaz'
4                 <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It works for the raw series output, but not for the rich html DataFrame output. I really care about the latter, but I didn't specify that in the question. I will edit that in now.